# How to broadcast array of parameters onto matrix of functions?

Tags: python, function, numpy, array-broadcasting

Given a matrix of functions (every function can have a different logic). The shape is `[N, x]`.

```
matrix_of_functions = [
    [fun11, fun12, fun13],
    [fun21, fun22, fun23],
    ...
    [funN1, funN2, funN3]
]
```

There is also an array of parameters with shape `[x]`.

```
array_of_parameters = [param1, param2, param3]
```

This dimension has the same size `x`. The parameters should broadcast over this dimension and the function should be applied.

The resulting matrix therefore is (should be a `numpy` array in the end):

```
matrix_of_results = [
    [fun11(param1), fun12(param2), fun13(param3)],
    [fun21(param1), fun22(param2), fun23(param3)],
    ...
    [funN1(param1), funN2(param2), funN3(param3)]
]
```

**It feels like there has to be a beautiful way to do this, but how?**

Obviously, this could be done like this:

```
matrix_of_results = []
for array_of_functions in matrix_of_functions:
    array_of_results = [fun(param) for fun, param in zip(array_of_functions, array_of_parameters])]:
    matrix_of_results.append(array_of_results )
```

Or more compact:

```
matrix_of_results = [
    [fun(param) for fun, param in zip(array_of_functions, array_of_parameters])] 
    for array_of_functions in matrix_of_functions
]
```

Or many other ways... but that is neither readable nor beautiful.

I did hope that there is a `numpy` ish way. Meaning, that the broadcasting is automatically handled since the shapes `[N, x]` and `[x]` are broadcastable. But that doesn't seem to be the case (`np.vectorize` does only take a single function and not a list or matrix of functions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345765/numpy-apply-an-array-of-functions-to-a-same-length-2d-array-of-value-as-if-mult

Comment: @mephisto Yes, that actually works. The other question is defined the other way around but it still applies to my question.

Comment: Since it is not a duplicate but the solution to that question helped to solve this, I will write an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mephisto pointed me to another question that contained a similar goal: [Numpy: Apply an array of functions to a same length 2d-array of value as if multiplying elementwise? (using a python function as an operator?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345765)

The difference is, that the other question was about broadcasting an array of functions to a matrix of parameters.
The good part is, that the answer also applies in the case where we try to map an array of parameters to a matrix of functions.

The solution was `np.vectorize` after all:

```
apply_vectorized = np.vectorize(lambda f, x: f(x))
matrix_of_results = apply_vectorized(matrix_of_functions, array_of_parameters)
```

The `apply_vectorized` method is exactly what I was looking for.
I did hope that this functionality would come out of the box and that I would not have to implement a helper function, but I can live with that.

Comment: Keep in mind that `np.vectorize` is not a performance tool.  For handling broadcasting issues like this it is nice, but generally is slower than iterations, especially pure list iterations.  A variant is `np.frompyfunc`, but the same time limitations.

Comment: Why are you bothered about that `lambda f,x` function?  In python a function is a 'first class object', and can be an element of an object dtype array.  But the standard way of calling a function is with the `f(x)` syntax.  `numpy` has not added any function or tool to iterate over an array and do this.   The fast core of `numpy` is numeric - applying a limited set of operations to numeric arrays.

Comment: @jpaulj: The matrix and array are not going to be huge so performance is a non issue. What do you mean regarding `lambda f,x`? Could you explain? I didn't get what you are trying to say.